# Need .htaccess rewrite example

Tags: .htaccess, permalinks, dynamic-links

Hello I want to create my sites links to dynamically, and for me need to create links in .htacces from

```
http://rude.su.lt~/veikutis/katalogas.php?link=dulkiu-siurbliai&id=1
```

to

```
http://rude.su.lt/~veikutis/dulkiu-siurbliai/1/
```

in PHP I redirect firs link to second link with function:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location: '.$location);
```

and now for me need to open that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is untested, of course, but should get you started:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^~veikutis/([a-zA-Z-]+)/(\d+)/? ~veikutis/katalogas.php?link=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Two components `/([a-zA-Z-]+)` and `/(\d+)` are captured as `$1, $2` and an optional trailing slash is included at the end `/?`.